# WinUI3 Adding cookie in webview2 not working

Tags: c#, windows, winui-3, webview2

I wrote the following code of WinUI 3.
This code aims to set a cookie using `CoreWebView2.CookieManager.AddOrUpdateCookie(Cookie)`
but the cookie wasn't set when webview2 initialized. (I confirmed it using the DevTools in webview2.)
Also, the app never crashed.
Are there any solutions?

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Window
    x:Class="WebView.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:WebView"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:controls="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <controls:WebView2 x:Name="MyWebView"  Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
        Source="https://www.microsoft.com" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Navigation;
using Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;

namespace WebView
{
    public sealed partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            MyWebView.CoreWebView2Initialized += WebviewLoaded;
        }

        public async void WebviewLoaded(WebView2 sender, CoreWebView2InitializedEventArgs args)
        {
            await MyWebView.EnsureCoreWebView2Async();
                var Cookie = MyWebView.CoreWebView2.CookieManager.CreateCookie("testcookie", "value", "https://test.com", "/");
                Cookie.IsHttpOnly = true;
                Cookie.IsSecure = true;
                Cookie.Expires = (DateTime.Now.AddDays(10).Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1))).TotalSeconds;
                Cookie.SameSite = CoreWebView2CookieSameSiteKind.None;
            MyWebView.CoreWebView2.CookieManager.AddOrUpdateCookie(Cookie);
        }
    }
}
```

I refreshed my OS and ran this app again but the result was the same.

Comment: Is this only a WinUI3? ie: does it works with Winforms or WPF?

Comment: Sorry, when trying to make WPF version, I found that AddOrUpdateCookie worked if the cookie domain is the same as webview.source. My problem was solved. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: You should answer yourself with explanation if you're happy

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.
Before we call `CoreWebView2.CookieManager.AddOrUpdateCookie(Cookie)`, WebView must have access to the site of the cookie.
In this case, default url of webview is microsoft.com, so I changed the domain of cookie like that

Before

`var Cookie = MyWebView.CoreWebView2.CookieManager.CreateCookie("testcookie", "value", "https://test.com", "/");`

After

`var Cookie = MyWebView.CoreWebView2.CookieManager.CreateCookie("testcookie", "value", ".microsoft.com", "/");`